# Add a Buyer Role to a User programatically

Tags: user-management

Imagine i have "MyDomain\Buyer" role in Role Manager, i want to get that role from role manager and add that role to a user programmatically using c#. can any one let me know how to do it. i am using sitecore 9 version.

Comment: this can help you..just read it - http://sitecorecodesamples.blogspot.com/2010/11/programmatically-addedit-users.html